# Alternative way to use repetitive file handle statements in Perl

Tags: file, perl, file-io

In Perl, to avoid repeating code, a design no, I tried to use the same file handle for writing the same text file to 2 different directories.  Based on from executing my code, I found out that it is not allowable although I could be missing something.  Can you use the same file handle for writing a text file and storing them in 2 different directories?

Looking for a better way.  How can I write the same text file to 2 different directories without duplicating and repeating code?  Like the occurence of repetiton happening in these 2 statements below:

```
open (my $fh_w1, ">$path1/$write_File");
open (my $fh_w2, ">$path2/$write_File");
```

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;


my $read_File = 'dataIn.txt';

my $path1 = 'C:\Perl\textfiles';
my $path2 = 'C:\Perl\databases';

my $write_File = 'dataOut.txt';

#open file for reading
open my $fh_r, '<', $read_File or die qq{Unable to open "$read_File" for input: $!};

#open file for writing
open (my $fh_w1, ">$path1/$write_File");
open (my $fh_w2, ">$path2/$write_File");
```

Comment: ug, rather than reusing vars, use curlies to delimit the obviously different pieces of of your code.

Comment: how about creating a symlink?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you open a file whatever else that filehandle is attached to is closed first. From [close](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/close.html)

> You don't have to close FILEHANDLE if you are immediately going to do another open on it, because open closes it for you.

So you can do

```
open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";
...
open $fh, '>', $out_file ...
...
open $fh, '>', $another_file ...
```

This does deprive you of opportunity to check for errors on `close $fh`, which is *not* done with an automatic close. Also, the line counter `$.` is not reset this way.

The filehandle cannot be declared repeatedly though, as the shown code does. Being a normal lexical variable you can only have one `my` declaration in a given scope.

Or, you can write a sub that opens a file, or writes it out altogether.

Finally, there are modules which reduce code to one line, like [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny)

```
use Path::Tiny;
...
path($file)->spew(@data);
```

which also nicely checks for errors and croaks if something is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Perl  [File::Copy](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Copy.html) module is capable of providing copy and move features We can wrap them in subroutine to achieve the same

```
use File::Copy;
copy("sourcefile","destinationfile") or die "Copy failed: $!";
copy("Copy.pm",\*STDOUT);
move("/dev1/sourcefile","/dev2/destinationfile");
use File::Copy "cp";
$n = FileHandle->new("/a/file","r");
cp($n,"x");
```